# Problems in installing MATLAB engine for python - only writing the .egg file in site-package

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda

When I am using python setup.py install in the matlabroot directory, I get the following prompt.

> Writing
> py38\Lib\site-packages\matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.8.egg-info

When I try to run in jupyter notebook, here is what I got:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlab.engine'; 'matlab' is not a package

I checked with the `conda list` and I found that the package name is `matlabengineforpython`, but not `matlab`. I tried to extract the .egg package, and put the matlab folder into path directory, but the `ModuleNotFoundError` still keeps showing.

Inside my `site-packages` folder, there is only one related folder called `\matlabengineforpython-R2022a-py3.8.egg\`

What should I do next to fix this configuration problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Here is a supplementary picture for my package list]

My package is not named as matlab but `matlabengineforpython`.

Comment: I fixed the problem by directly move the matlab folder to the site-package folder, and delete a extra matlab.py file.